# Readonly route parameter in Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Here's my example route:

```
routes.subcategory.type = "Router_Route_Subcat"
routes.subcategory.route = "([^/]+)/([^/]+)"
routes.subcategory.defaults.controller = "Category"
routes.subcategory.defaults.action = "sub-category"
routes.subcategory.map.1 = "category"
routes.subcategory.map.2 = "subcategory"
routes.subcategory.reverse = "%s/%s"
```

now I would like to add a parameter to the request object, which is easy enough by doing:

```
routes.subcategory.defaults.year = "2010"
```

In the action I can then do:

```
getRequest()->getParam('year');
```

But I want to be 100% sure that this 'year' parameter can not be set or overwritten from the outside world, not by adding query parameters to the URL, nor by posting the year parameter to the URL.

If I try it out I can't seem to change it, but can I be sure?

Comment: why do you have to have that param in the router? why dont you declare it inside the controller or make it a constructor parameter to either the controller or the processing object?

Comment: Because I'm using the parameter in a frontcontroller plugin.

Comment: Another possible usage could be when you have several routes mapping to the same controller/action. Ofcourse you could route them to different actions and then call the same parametrized method from there, but setting a request parameter on the route can be more elegant in such case.